# mod_rewrite redirects screw up paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's a redirect I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

The problem is if I type `http://www.example.com/apple` it's OK when it comes to my links on the page.

BUT if I use `http://www.example.com/apple/` (notice last slash) then links are all screwed up.

How do I write the .htaccess so links will not include the last slash and not screw up links on page?

Update: I ended up using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip the trailing slash with the following first:

[remove-those-trailing-slashes-from-your-uris](http://justinblanton.com/2006/09/remove-those-trailing-slashes-from-your-uris)

Then process as normal after that point.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using absolute URL paths or absolute URLs to reference external resources.

Because relative URLs are resolved from a base URL, that is the URL of the current documen if not declared otherwise (see [`BASE` HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)). So if you reference `/baz/quux` using just the relative URL path `baz/quux` it would be resolved correctly to `/baz/quux` when used in `/foo`, but it would be resolved to `/foo/baz/quux` when used in `/foo/bar`. But the absolute URL path `/baz/quux` is always resolved to `/baz/quux`.